# Laravel & Vite - Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'public/hot'

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, vite, laravel-sail

Installed a fresh laravel project with sail, tried running npm run dev and get this error returned.

I have tried updating the ownership of the node modules but no luck.

How do I just run dev?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXvjA.png)